# Type Error: message.createReactionCollector is not a function Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a gambling system for my bot. I use discord.js and tried to make a reaction collector to choose what game they want to play. Idk why the create a reaction collector is not a function, so maybe its just me.

Here is the code:

```
run(message) {

    const embed = new RichEmbed()
   .setColor(1)
   .setTitle(`Welcome to the gambling center! Please select a game to play!`)
   .addBlankField(true)
   .addField(`:one:`, `Gamble away to win double or nothin!`)
   .addBlankField(true)
   .addField(`:two:`, `Gamble like the lottery to have a chance to win big!`)
   .addBlankField(true)
   let m = message.channel.send({embed}).then((m)=>{
        m.react('\u0031\u20E3')
        m.react('\u0032\u20E3')
    }).then(()=>{
        const collector = message.createReactionCollector((reaction, user) => 
            user.id === message.author.id &&
            reaction.emoji.name === "\u0031\u20E3" ||
            reaction.emoji.name === "\u0032\u20E3" 
        ).once("collect", reaction => {
             const chosen = reaction.emoji.name;
                 if(chosen === "\u0031\u20E3"){
                    message.channel.send(`Double or Nothin!`)
                }else{(chosen === "\u0032\u20E3")
                message.channel.send(`Lottery!`)}
collector.stop()});
    })  
}
```

Here is the full error that pops up:

```
(node:5948) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.createReactionCollector is not a function
at message.channel.send.then.then (C:\Users\patri\Documents\Super Dev\commands\Economy\Gamble.js:36:39)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
(node:5948) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5948) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Any help would be appreciated! (Sorry if it's a little messy.)

Comment: Hi, could you post the full error to help us help you? Thanks!

Comment: Yea, I inserted the full error, not much to work with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are sending a message but using a different message object. Try making the variable m the reaction collector

Comment: Yea the issue is the m variable not being able to pass by the next .then, it works without the .then but does not make it work properly. I need a solution to get the m variable to pass the second .then (if that makes any sense..)

Comment: Return m in the first .then - you should be able to get the variable in the second .then